# How to switch cases while using lodash in react native

Tags: react-native

I have written the following code in which I have used lodash to show the first letter of a word in capital but there to other words where all the words will we in capital for eg. 1. Private Limited and 2. HUF) in this in Private Limited I want to show Private "P" as capital and in HUF I want to show "HUF" all in capital, so can use please tell how can I use cases in this to check when to use which lodash property.

```
<View style={[KycDetailsStyles.basicContainer, KycDetailsStyles.infoContainer]}>
      {renderCompanyInfo(
        appStrings.natureOfCompanyStrings.typeOfCompany,
        props.customerData.companyType ? _.upperFirst(props.customerData.companyType) : '-',
      )}
</View>
```

Comment: upperFirst will return HUF so what is wrong ?

Comment: upperFirst will return Huf but I want it as HUF and for Private Limited it should be "Private Limited". For Private Limited upperFirst is Okay but for Huf I want all words in Caps, so I have to use cases to check when to use which property.

Comment: I test it and If I put HUF it return HUF https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-moon-zq5g1?file=/src/index.js

Comment: but can you tell me how can I use switch cases to use two different property of lodash.